# No such file or directory error in PBXCopyFilesBuildPhase XCode

Tags: xcode, macos, xcodebuild

To start with i am beginner in xcode but want to find out an issue in the existing project.

I have a cocoa application in which i add a jar file and a folder downloaded from central package manager to appbundle.

We have written couple of copybuild phases for this which copy these files from a location "contents"(inside the project location) to "Java resources " and "Plugins" destinations.

This project location "contents" does not exist at the beginning but gets created after the files are downloaded from our package manager.

So in design time xcode i am referring to a location which does not exist at that time but will be later created during build/run time.

Now these downloaded files have to be copied to our desitnations. But this copy build phase is failing in our central build server triggering xcodebuild from jenkins.

Same stuff is passing in local since i copy the files from an already downloaded and present files location called "contents" (the part of downloading from package manager and creating the "contents" folder is skipped in local build )

Error which i get from builtin-copy task is "No such file or directory" for the jar file to be resolved from the "contents" location.

Source location is properly resolved and also the files are present in jenkins workspace but still i get the error.

**Question is,  is the reference to "contents" location properly resolved during build time ? Can a reference to a location (which is not present intially) be made at design time to be resolved later in build time ?**

Hope i was able to clear my question . PLease let me know if i need to provide any further info

Best Regards,

Saurav

Comment: Why not create the contents location, even if it's just a placeholder?

Comment: It was a silly mistake as there was a space in the file path name and hence file was not found...apologies to them who wasted some of their time to analyse the question